# alternative to crt malloc function (NASM)?

Tags: windows, nasm

Is there any alternative way to create dynamic memory in Windows with NASM instead of using the `malloc()` function of the msvcrt lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not at a computer.....  search msdn at Microsoft for the following APIs
VirtualAlloc
HeapAlloc
GlobalAlloc

each has their place of use

Comment: This, or, `MapViewOfFile` :-)